# Trouble splitting date-time columns and avoiding chr type + time always adds todays date

Tags: r, sorting, datetime, split

I am on a case study for a Analytics course. I loaded various csv-files into R along with common libraries to use such as tidyverse, janitor etc.

Now, I have 2 datasets that have date-time in one columnm and are chr type. One is sleep or sleep_new. I added pictures and code to illustrate my current results below.

I manage either to separate the two columns and they remain chr types.I can not transform the time column in only time. R will always add todays date to it.

On the flip side when I manage to add the date-time format and change the type, I can not split the column without loosing the type or getting date added to time.

In the end I want to only maintain the two new columns in date and time format, not chr.

By now I am just blind to my mistakes as I tried a gazillion of ways but ran into errors on one side or the other. Obviously I am a bloody beginner and my logical thinking for code is limited.

Would be happy to get some help.

I have used the following code pieces so far:

**1.Changing from chr to dttm type**

```
    sleep_new <- sleep %>%  
    rename(datetime = SleepDay)%>%
    mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

- this works but know I can't manage to split it into two separate columns

  more precisely I want to split the date time column into date and time and keep the position to two columns [2][3] without having the datetimne column.

**2. For splitting the column I used:**

```
    sleep_new$date <- format(sleep_new$datetime, format = "%m/%d/%y")
    sleep_new$time <- format(sleep_new$datetime, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

- this works but put the column position to the end of the table and obviously keeps the date time column

**3. Another post on Stackoverflow suggested this:**

```
    df$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(df$Start,format="%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")
    df$Date <- format(as.POSIXct(df$Start,format="%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"),"%Y:%m:%d")
```

which I translated to my case:

```
    sleep_new$time <- format(as.POSIXct(sleep_new$datetime,format="%Y:%m:%d    %H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")

    sleep_new$date <- format(as.POSIXct(sleep_new$datetime,format="%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"),"%Y:%m:%d")
```

- however it is equally not working as it out puts the two columns in chr type.

Here are the sample images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use `dput()` to share your data rather than uploading an image of it. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Base R doesn’t come with a “time-only” class. You could use the one from the hms package:

```r
x <- "2023-05-30 12:30:00"
dttm <- strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
data.frame(
  dttm = as.POSIXct(dttm),
  date = as.Date(dttm),
  time = hms::as_hms(dttm)
)
#>                  dttm       date     time
#> 1 2023-05-30 12:30:00 2023-05-30 12:30:00
```